# Strophe Unrecoverable TLS error

Tags: ssl, xmpp, ejabberd, libstrophe

I am developing a simple ejabberd client in C using libstrophe. It connects and begins to handle messages as it's supposed to do.

However, after a while (following two or three pings from the ejabberd server), my connection closes and the status is set to `DISCONNECTED`. Below is the tail of the debug lines:

```
xmpp DEBUG Unrecoverable TLS error, 5. 
xmpp DEBUG Closing socket.
DEBUG: disconnected event DEBUG Stopping event loop. 
event DEBUG Event
oop completed.
```

I initialize and connect as below.

```
xmpp_initialize();

/* read connection params */
if( set_xmpp_conn_params( &conn_params ) < 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not retrieve connection params from %s\n", 
                    SERVER_CONF_FILE);
    return -1;
}

/* initialize the XMPP logger */
xmpp_log = xmpp_get_default_logger(XMPP_LOG_LEVEL);
xmpp_ctx = xmpp_ctx_new(NULL, xmpp_log);

/* create a connection */
xmpp_conn = xmpp_conn_new(xmpp_ctx);

/* login */
xmpp_conn_set_jid(xmpp_conn, conn_params.jid);
xmpp_conn_set_pass(xmpp_conn, conn_params.password);

/* create a client */
xmpp_connect_client(    xmpp_conn, conn_params.host, 0, 
                        agent_conn_handler, xmpp_ctx );

/* enter the event loop */
xmpp_run( xmpp_ctx );

/*  the code below is executed 
    whenever connection handler @agent_conn_handler exits */

/* release the connection and context */
xmpp_conn_release(xmpp_conn);
xmpp_ctx_free(xmpp_ctx);
```

Why am I getting that TLS error message?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using openssl, gnutls, or schannel for TLS?

Comment: Yes, I am using `openssl`.

Answer (score 0):

Error 5 is SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL.  The OpenSSL [docs](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_error.html) say:

> Some I/O error occurred. The OpenSSL error queue may contain more
>   information on the error. If the error queue is empty (i.e.
>   ERR_get_error() returns 0), ret can be used to find out more about the
>   error: If ret == 0, an EOF was observed that violates the protocol. If
>   ret == -1, the underlying BIO reported an I/O error (for socket I/O on
>   Unix systems, consult errno for details).

In practice, this may mean the server dropped your connection for some reason.  I'd suggest doing a packet trace with [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to get more info.  For example, we have seen this happen with servers that use the RSA libraries for TLS, when the client offers TLS version 1.1.

Comment: As I look through the Wireshark, before disconnecting, the client first sends a `[FIN, ACK]` packet to and then receives a RST from the server. How did you resolve your case?

Comment: Does the server send a FIN before the client sends FIN/ACK?  Also, decode the stream as SSL, and look to see what the last SSL message was.  In the case we saw, we had to force clients to use TLS 1.0 until we replaced the RSA library on the server.

Comment: hi, I'am creating an application using libstrophe as XMPP client, would you happen to have an experience regarding "Unrecoverable TLS error, 6." ?